# Many-pins & still-simple IC, how to prototype with it?

Tags: integrated-circuit, connector, breadboard, pins, prototyping

I'm building my second project, it will use TI TVP5146 video decoder, which has 80-pins, and TI Tiva C. What prototyping accessories will I need? I think it can be clearly stated what such many-pins & still-simple IC needs. I must avoid re-ordering because of very low budget. Please, help me resolve this without blind orders.

Will I need large breadboard, or PCB-like board? The project has to handle multiple video inputs: SCART, composite, S-Video. How to connect those cables to the prototyping-board, how to resolve input pin's different roles depending on cable being used? I could need some prototyping-board just for the cables? Maybe it can be predicted what commonly used registers and capacitors will be needed, or maybe there's a source to find some reference on this?

Comment: *Will I need large breadboard, or PCB-like board?* I would simply **forget** about using this IC on a breadboard or any kind of experimental PCB. For this kind of complexity you need a PCB designed for this IC. It sits in a TQFP package, you cannot solder that without at least a hot air gun. If you choose to go ahead with this I think it will be a **miracle** if you can get it to work at all.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: This is really helpful, thanks! Would having a PCB project already available help? I found a decoder chip that has PCB bundled in datasheet: http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/85927/AD/ADV7181/2413/93/ADV7181.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way of breadboarding with this sort of part, other than simply completing a design and building it is to start with an evaluation board.

This can also serve as an example of how to apply the part since the manufacturer is usually motivated to show off the part in a good light, so it will be surrounded by the required parts and deployed in such a way to allow it to perform at close to datasheet numbers. There will also be a PCB layout and you can learn from the specifications of that (number of layers, ground and power planes used etc.).

For more complex chips they may supply software that will allow you to change registers etc. without coding.

In this case, the evaluation board is the [TVP5146EVM](http://www.ti.com/tool/tvp5146evm), and it costs $450 or so, with free (U.S.) shipping direct from TI. The [BOM](http://www.ti.com/lit/df/sler015/sler015.pdf) includes more than 150 parts, so this seems like a decent price to me if you have a serious application. I don't see Gerbers for the board, but the software and schematic are provided. It does require a **PC with a parallel printer port** since there is no micro on the EVM.

The final sentence in the above paragraph should give you some pause- this part is more than 13 years old, which is fairly long in the tooth for a video part.

Comment: I've found SD video decoder that apparently includes complete PCB layout. Do you think this makes things easier? http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/85927/AD/ADV7181/2413/93/ADV7181.html (PDF of the document has a different PCB image, curiously).

Comment: Any time you have a PCB layout with required layout and bypass caps, support parts etc. it's going to make it way easier. Even 4-layer boards are not that expensive to have made these days.